# Delete lines from row num A to row num B in vim

Tags: vim

How to delete lines from rows of particular numbers in vim?

E.g. I would like to remove lines from rows 1000-1999.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225366/vim-to-delete-a-range-of-lines-into-a-register

Comment: `:help :range` has all the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete from row number to number:

```
:1000,1999d
```

Delete from current line to number:

```
:,123d
```

(or in Normal mode `d123G`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
:1000,1999d
```

See `:help d` and `:help range`.