# copying everything from line number xxxxx to line number zzzzzz in vi editor

Tags: unix, vi

I would like to copy a couple of screenful lines using `vi` editor. Anything from line number `xxxx` to line number `zzzzz`.

Then, I want to write these lines into another file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim yanking range of lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023015/vim-yanking-range-of-lines)

Comment: From your comment it looks like you want to use these lines outside `vi`. Could you indicate what is your final goal?

Comment: true, I want to copy a part of the file to another  file. I don't need the first 23232 lines nor the last 7263726 lines only the middle 76337 lines.

Comment: but I swear I am tempted to write a complete java io program to do this.

Comment: Haha don't! And where do you want to insert those lines? At the end of a given file?

Comment: I'd like to create a brand new file, and insert the lines there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in `vi` then you can use:

```
:XXX,ZZZy<enter>
```

However, it looks like you want to store these lines in another file. Then, `awk` comes handy:

```
awk 'NR==XXX,NR==ZZZ' a > new_file
```

If the numbers happen to be variables, use them as this:

```
awk -v first="$first" -v last="$last" 'NR==first,NR==last' a > new_file
```

#### Test

Let's print a sequence of 50 numbers in the file `a`, each one in a different line:
    $ seq 50 > a

Then, we produce the output:

```
$ awk 'NR==5,NR==7' a > new_file
$ cat new_file
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 2):

In the command mode (hit <ESC>) type:

```
:X,Zy
```

Where`X` is the first line and `Z` is the last line.

### Example

Copy lines 3 to 500:

```
:3,500y
```

To insert go to the line **after** which you want to instert the copies lines and hit `p` (lower 'P').

If you want to insert the lines befor a particular line then hit `P` (upper 'P').